# Integration with respect to $\nu=\mu_1-\mu_2$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, signed-measures

Let $\nu=\mu_1-\mu_2$ be a signed measure written as the difference of two finite positive measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$ on the measure space $(X,\Sigma)$. Let $\nu=\nu^+-\nu^-$ be its Jordan decomposition, let $f:X\to \mathbb R$ be measurable and suppose that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu_1,\mu_2$.

Since $\nu^+\leq \mu_1$ and $\nu^-\leq \mu_2$ we have that $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu^+,\nu^-$. Moreover from

$$\mu_1+\nu^-=\mu_2+\nu^+$$

we get that

$$\int f \,d\mu_1+\int f \,d\nu^-=\int f \,d\mu_2+ \int f \,d\nu^+$$

or $$\int f \,d\nu=\int f \,d\mu_1-\int f \,d\mu_2 \quad \quad (1)$$

**Question:** Does $(1)$ still holds if we assume  $f$ integrable with respect to $\nu^+,\nu^-$?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu$ iff it is integrable with respect to $|\nu|$, the variation function. In particular, if $\nu$ is real valued, $f$ is integrable with respect to $\nu$ iff it is integrable with respect to $\nu_+$ and $\nu_-$. Under this conditions, (1) holds. If $f$ is integrable with respect the positive part (resp. negative part) of $\nu$, but not with respect to the other,  (1) may fail.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ integrable with respect to $\nu_+$, $\nu_-$ implies $f$ integrable with respect to $\mu_1,\mu_2$? Otherwise $(1)$ cannot hold.

Comment: What I said is that if $f$ is integrable w.r.t $\nu_+$ and $\nu_-$, then $f$ is integrable with respect to $|\nu|=\nu_++\nu_-$. and vice versa. In which case $\int f\,d\nu=\int f\,d\nu_+ - \int f\,d\nu_-$

Comment: @OliverDiaz Ok but how is this related to $(1)$ ? Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: TO me the natural decomposition $\nu-\nu_+-\nu_-$ is what matters. For other decompositions, as Danny showed in his example, the answer is no.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You may end up with $\infty-\infty$. One obvious example is that $\nu=0$. In this case $\nu^+=\nu^-=0$. However, we may choose any finite measure $\mu$ and write $\nu=\mu-\mu$. Choose a non-negative measurable function $f$ such that $\int f du=\infty$...

Comment: Thank you I should have thought about that. And is my reasoning correct for the case where $f$ is integrable with respect to $\mu_1,\mu_2$?

Comment: @Alphie I think your reasoning is correct yes (if you are still interested).