# If $\lambda = \mu-\nu$, is it true that $\int f \mathrm d \lambda^+- \int f \mathrm d \lambda^- = \int f \mathrm d \mu -\int f \mathrm d \nu$?

Tags: integration, measure-theory, signed-measures

People usually write $\int f \mathrm d (\mu-\nu)$ as a shorthand for $\int f \mathrm d \mu -\int f \mathrm d \nu$.

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ be a measure space and $\mathcal M :=\mathcal M(\Omega)$ the space of all finite signed measures on $\Omega$. Let $\lambda \in \mathcal M$ and $(\lambda^+, \lambda^-)$ be its unique Jordan decomposition. Assume there are non-negative measures $\mu, \nu \in \mathcal M$ such that $\lambda = \mu-\nu$. Assume that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. both $\lambda^+$ and $\lambda^-$. Then we define
$$
\int f \mathrm d \lambda := \int f \mathrm d \lambda^+- \int f \mathrm d \lambda^-.
$$

> Can we prove that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. both $\mu$ and $\nu$? If yes, can we show that
> $$
> \int f \mathrm d \lambda = \int f \mathrm d \mu -\int f \mathrm d \nu
> $$
> ?

---

**Update:** I have found a related question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4273701/integration-with-respect-to-nu-mu-1-mu-2?rq=1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. $\lambda =(\mu+\tau)-(\nu +\tau)$ for any finite positive measure $\tau$ and we can certainly have $\int f d (\mu+\tau)=\infty$. I will let you write out an explicit counter-example.

Comment: What about now if I impose more that $f$ is integrable w.r.t. both $\mu$ and $\nu$.

Comment: In that case the equation is correct.

Comment: Do you have a reference for it?

Comment: Just prove it for simple functions and the take limits. @Akira